# How to fix "Exceeded asset access limit" error when trying to get the full list of pages (accounts) a user has a role on from facebook graph api

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am building a Laravel 5 app to get the facebook page insights for my client. I am using the Facebook PHP business SDK to make calls to the facebook graph API. The problem appears when I try to get the full list of pages a user has a role on. The app was reviewed by Facebook and has `manage_pages` permission granted (I know there is a `pages_show_list` permission but in the docs is specified that any of them will work).

The procedure is simple and very similar to this code:
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-business-sdk/blob/master/examples/UserAccountsEdge.php

where `$access_token` is the user access token, not the page access token because the page access token will be sent by the graph API in the response.

I am getting this error from the Graph API:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Application request limit reached",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "is_transient": false,
    "code": 4,
    "error_subcode": 1349193,
    "error_user_title": "Exceeded asset access limit",
    "error_user_msg": "You have exceeded asset access limit for the calling user. For asset type page, there is a limit to 3 instances the app can access for the caller.",
    "fbtrace_id": "AnTVYLGrhtjHlL7DgK0zB-A"
  }
}
```

Indeed the number of the items in the accounts (pages) list is limited to 3 and I do not know why. If a user has roles on 20 pages I just can’t get the complete list of those pages.

The errors disappear if I am using the `$limit => 3` (or less) field inside the $fields array. In this situation the response of the API looks like this (I deleted the real content to simplify the reading):

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "access_token": "...token...",
      "category": "...category name...",
      "category_list": [
        {
          "id": "...id...",
          "name": "...name..."
        }
      ],
      "name": "...page name...",
      "id": "...page id...",
      "tasks": [
        "ANALYZE",
        "ADVERTISE",
        "MODERATE",
        "CREATE_CONTENT",
        "MANAGE"
      ]
    },
    {
      "access_token": "...token...",
      "category": "...category name...",
      "category_list": [
        {
          "id": "...id...",
          "name": "...name..."
        }
      ],
      "name": "...page name...",
      "id": "...page id...",
      "tasks": [
        "ANALYZE",
        "ADVERTISE",
        "MODERATE",
        "CREATE_CONTENT",
        "MANAGE"
      ]
    },
    {
      "access_token": "...token...",
      "category": "...category name...",
      "category_list": [
        {
          "id": "...id...",
          "name": "...name..."
        }
      ],
      "name": "...page name...",
      "id": "...page id...",
      "tasks": [
        "ANALYZE",
        "ADVERTISE",
        "MODERATE",
        "CREATE_CONTENT",
        "MANAGE"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "...",
      "after": "..."
    },
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/...id.../accounts?access_token=...token..."
  }
}
```

I tried to use cursors, implicit fetching and iterations ( foreach, `$cursor->rewind(), $cursor->next()` ) to get previous / next items from the list but still no success. The limitation of 3 items in the accounts (pages) list cannot be exceeded. Has anybody encountered this problem and found a solution to it? I have spent many hours to search in the facebook developers docs for a solution or an explanation of this kind of rate limiting but found nothing related to this.

I have also used the Graph API Explorer to test the calls and the result is exactly the same.

Comment: In https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/348631119141897/ they say this was expected behavior, if your app is in “individual verification”, and not belonging to a business. Suggest you join that bug report and ask for clarification.

Comment: Thanks **misorude** this may be the issue in my situation, I will check.

Comment: Looks like I'm limited to 1 page now - paging doesn't work either so I can't make a request per page.

Comment: hello guys, any of you could resolve the issue? I had now passed the business verification, but still has the error :/